# Swift Array var issue

Tags: arrays, swift, var

```
    var dictionary = ["1": ["One","Two","Three"],
                      "2": ["A","B","C"]
                     ]

    var array = dictionary ["1"]
    array!.append("Four")

    print("array Count: \(array!.count) array In DictionaryCount: \(dictionary ["1"]!.count)")
    //array Count: 4 array In Dictionary Count: 3
```

var array has append "Four",but in dictionary it does't, how to append an element in dictionary?

Comment: yes as said by @ozgur direct append will not work. you can do that or just reassign the array to `dictionary["1"] = array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Objective-C, collections in Swift are not reference types. It means that arrays, dictionaries, strings and almost everything behave like primitives in C/Objective-C (except objects, which are instances of classes, not structures or enums)

You can find more details in this official Apple page: [Value and Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, arrays are implemented as [structs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) and they are always copied when they are passed around in your code, and do not use reference counting. That being said, `array` becomes the copy of `dictionary[1]` in your example so updating the contents of that doesn't affect the original dictionary.

What you should do instead:

```
dictionary["1"]?.append("Four")
```